# Is marking a trail a bluff or a survival check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Its entirely possible to mark a trail in the forest or many other terrains for others to follow, but what kind of checks would be involved?

To pass a secret message which marking a trail for your group to follow and not others should count as, is a bluff check, but that doesnt really make sense in this case. Performing a survival check is a much better choice.

But to pick up on the marked path, would that still be a sense motive or should it also be survival?

Comment: ahh, Pathfinder path-finder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would assume based on the context of the skill that it would be a Survival check. Survival is specifically used for surviving in the wilderness, tracking, etc. While Bluff normally involves lying to people during speaking to them and is countered by Sense Motive. In a Survival context you're marking a trail so that you can notice the signs and follow it, and so that others skilled in Survival won't notice your own personal trail markings. You wouldn't be able to accomplish this without knowledge about trails, or without the Survival in general. So it's likely you would use this skill.

Comment: Are you not also able to hide the markings from other people searching for you?

Comment: If there was a trail marking you are trying to notice made by another person, you'd likely have to roll an opposed survival check to notice their markings, however once you noticed them you'd be able to get rid of them.